# I can't get the Perspective Camera to follow the player. Camera is stuck to the World origin

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm new to THREE.js.

For the purpose of learning JavaScript and THREE.js I made this (kind of) Mini Game where player is able to explore space and different space objects (work in process).

Anyways, my problem is when the scene and objects are rendered, and you start moving your cuboid, **camera** doesn't move with it (actually it **doesn't move away from the world origin**) **only rotates in place looking at the player's object**.

This is the code:

```
import './style.css'
import * as THREE from 'three'; 
import { OrbitControls } from 'three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls';

// Scene object
const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const clock = new THREE.Clock();

var cameraObject, keys;
var temp = new THREE.Vector3;
var dir = new THREE.Vector3;
var a = new THREE.Vector3;
var b = new THREE.Vector3;
var distance = 0.3;
var velocity = 0.0;
var speed = 0.0;

// Camera object
const perspectiveCamera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 25, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 50, 1e7 )
perspectiveCamera.position.setZ(80);
cameraObject = new THREE.Object3D;
cameraObject.add(perspectiveCamera);
// perspectiveCamera.lookAt(scene.position)

// Renderer object
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
});
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

// Renderer
renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
renderer.render( scene, perspectiveCamera )

// Light
// PointLight
const pointLight = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff)
pointLight.position.set(20,20,20)
// AmbientLight
const ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff)
scene.add(pointLight, ambientLight)

// Helper classes
const lightHelper = new THREE.PointLightHelper(pointLight);
const axesHelper = new THREE.AxesHelper(5);
scene.add(lightHelper, axesHelper)

// Controls
const controls = new OrbitControls(perspectiveCamera, renderer.domElement);
controls.movementSpeed = 1000;
controls.domElement = renderer.domElement;
controls.rollSpeed = Math.PI / 24;
controls.autoForward = false;
controls.dragToLook = false;

let cube = new THREE.Group();
const cubeGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(3,10,3)
const cubeMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x238423 })
const cube1 = new THREE.Mesh( cubeGeometry, cubeMaterial );
cube.add(cube1)
scene.add(cube)

// Objects
// Stars
function addStar() {
  const geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.25, 24, 24);
  const material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial( { color: 0xffffff })
  const star = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
  const [x, y, z] = Array(3).fill().map(() => THREE.MathUtils.randFloatSpread( 500 ));
  star.position.set(x,y,z);
  scene.add(star)
}
Array(1500).fill().forEach(addStar)

let keyState = {};
keys = {
  a: false,
  s: false,
  d: false,
  w: false,
  q: false,
  e: false,
  space: false,
  shiftleft: false,
};

document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  console.log(e.code);
  const key = e.code.replace('Key', '').toLowerCase();
    if ( keys[ key ] !== undefined )
      keys[ key ] = true;
});

document.body.addEventListener( 'keyup', function(e) {
    
  const key = e.code.replace('Key', '').toLowerCase();
  if ( keys[ key ] !== undefined )
    keys[ key ] = false;
});

// Animate objects
function animate() {
  const delta = clock.getDelta();

  requestAnimationFrame( animate );
  speed = 0.0;

  if ( keys.w )
    cube.rotateX(-0.03);

  if ( keys.s )
  cube.rotateX(0.03);

  if ( keys.a )
  cube.rotateZ(0.03);

  if ( keys.d )
  cube.rotateZ(-0.03);

  if ( keys.q )
  cube.rotateY(-0.06);

  if ( keys.e )
  cube.rotateY(0.06);

  if ( keys.space )
    speed = 0.9;

  velocity += ( speed - velocity ) * .3;
  cube.translateY( velocity );

  if ( keys.shiftleft )
    speed = 0.9*5;
    velocity += ( speed - velocity ) * .3; 
    cube.translateY( velocity );

  perspectiveCamera.lookAt( cube.position ); 
  controls.update(delta);
  renderer.render( scene, perspectiveCamera );
}
animate();
```

I'm actually trying to make some sort of Third Person Camera. In order to make the camera follow this little cuboid and rotate as the object rotates on the screen.

***First attempt:***

```
const idealOffset = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, -80);
function animate(){
  ...
  perspectiveCamera.position.set(0, 0, -80);
  perspectiveCamera.applyQuaternion(cube.rotation);
  perspectiveCamera.position.add(cube.position);
  perspectiveCamera.lookAt(idealOffset);
  ...
}
```

Camera moves with the cube but after a few seconds turns back to look at the world origin.

***Second attempt:***

```
// Animate objects
  requestAnimationFrame( function animate(milliseconds) {
  const delta = clock.getDelta();
  let moveDistance = 10*delta;
  let rotateAngle = Math.PI/2*delta;
  requestAnimationFrame( animate );
  speed = 0.0;

  if ( keys.w ){
    cube.rotateX(-0.03);
  }
  if ( keys.s ){
    cube.rotateX(0.03);
  }

  let rotation_matrix = new THREE.Matrix4().identity();
  if ( keys.a ){
    cube.rotateZ(rotateAngle);
  }
  if ( keys.d ){
    cube.rotateZ(-rotateAngle);
  }
  if ( keys.q ){
    cube.rotateY(-rotateAngle);
  }
  if ( keys.e ){
    cube.rotateY(rotateAngle);
  }
  if ( keys.space ){
    speed = 0.9;
    velocity += ( speed - velocity ) * .3;
    cube.translateY( velocity );
  }
  if ( keys.shiftleft ){
    speed = 0.9*5;
    velocity += ( speed - velocity ) * .3; 
    cube.translateY( velocity );
  }
  
  var relativeCameraOffset = new THREE.Vector3(0,-80,0);
  var cameraOffset = relativeCameraOffset.applyMatrix4(cube.matrixWorld);
  perspectiveCamera.position.x = cameraOffset.x;
  perspectiveCamera.position.y = cameraOffset.y;
  perspectiveCamera.position.z = cameraOffset.z;
  perspectiveCamera.lookAt(cube.position);
  renderer.render( scene, perspectiveCamera );
});
```

Camera does follow my cube but when I rotate it 180 DEG on x-axis it turns upside-down,it's fixed to the player and doesn't move smoothly and it looks directly at the player (back side of the cube).

This inspired me to read more about rotating/translating in 3d space, about Euler angles, quaternions, gimbal lock. I'm just not quite sure how to apply these scary quaternions to my project...

Any help, reference, whatever would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using OrbitControls, just update the `.target` property to the position of the object you want it to focus on. When the cube moves, the camera will move with it. See [here for more on the docs](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/controls/OrbitControls.target):

```
orbitControls.target = cube.position;
```

I'm not sure why you're doing this: `cameraObject.add(perspectiveCamera);`. This doesn't do anything if you don't make any changes to `cameraObject`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. This didn't give me the result I wanted. The camera is still glued to the center. As for the "cameraObject"...well, I was experimenting with perspective camera and quaternions...and I forgot to delete those two rows before posting the code. I edited my question to show you what I tried.